# Is every positive-definite matrix an H-matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Is every  positive-definite matrix an [H-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-matrix_(iterative_method)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20H%2Dmatrix,n%20%C3%97%20n%20complex%20matrix.)?

By positive-definite I mean matrices $A\in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$(not necessarily symmetric), such that for every $0 \neq x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$$x^TAx > 0.$$

I'm having trouble showing that a matrix is an H-matrix and i can't really find much about H-matrices, so any hint or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your definition of positive definiteness, no. Consider e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&-t\\ t&1}$ for a sufficiently large $t$.